# PHP algorithm for updating database records with new entries and removing missing ones without deleting currently saved entries

Tags: php, arrays, database, symfony

In the database I have multiple answer values to the questions:

Question1 -> answer1 answer2

Question2 -> answer3 answer4 answer5

--

Now user submits his updates to these answers:

Question1 -> answer1 answer2 answer6

Question2 -> answer3 answer4

--

So, what is the most optimal way to make these changes? I need to delete missing entries, add new ones without erasing old values.

The most simple way is to delete all older answers and just write new ones. But my system has soft delete so deleted entries are not really deleted just flagged with delete date. And if I do it this way, database table grows really quickly because it writes dozens new entries every time user makes an update.

Another way I can come up with is to do it in two iterations: first one compares saved values with new ones and removes saved ones if it doesnt find a match. And the second iteration compares new values with older ones and everything what is missing.

But maybe there is more practical, efficient way?

Comment: You shouldn't put multiple values in the same column value. You should have a table with a separate row for each question+answer, with a foreign key to the questions table.

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: use a question_id which is set to original row id if question_id is 0, and parent_id column all edits create new rows, linking back to the original question_id and previous edit via parent_id, then its simply a case of abit of ordering/group by on the select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the symfony property accessor component to handle the diff calculation for you.

On your question object you have to implement the `getAnswers()` method for reading the value, the `addAnswer($answer)` method to add a single answer and the `removeAnswer($answer)` to remove a single answer.

Then, in your controller/service/command, you have to inject the property accessor (`PropertyAccessorInterface`) and call `$propertyAccess->setValue($question, 'answers', $newAnswers);`

That will call the adder and the remover only for changed values.